# getting the error while doing the multiple requests during the load testing

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, microservices

I have do the load test for the api via jmeter.  api builds in the microservce architecture and when i testing this i get an error like this on server randomly with 400 response code **"Error calling via grpc: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. IOException: The request was aborted. IOException: The response ended prematurely while waiting for the next frame from the server.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.") - Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. IOException: The request was aborted. IOException: The response ended prematurely while waiting for the next frame from the server.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.")"** can any one is having idea about this error if any then please share the reference link.

i have to do the load testing.

Answer (score 0):

Without having too many details, what I can tell you is to check in the Sampler sending the request, the address.
Are you using and IP / Port or hostname?
Are you using http / https?
Maybe orth checking the documentation of what clients need to do at https://grpc.io/ since it seems a little more complex than a simple http request.

Comment: i used the https protocol